# Where should I put a PHP include/require statement in HTML?

Tags: php, html, class, character-encoding

I created a PHP class inside a file, and now I want to use it in my HTML pages.

Where should I put the `require` or `include` statement inside the HTML page?

Is there a *performance* difference between load it at the beginning or at the end of the HTML, or is there no difference at all?

Should be the `<meta charset="X">` before than the PHP script, so if the class is too long I won't have any problem with the char sets?

Example:

```php
<?php
    //Should I load the class here?

    //include "/var/www/php/db.php";
    //$classDB = 'DB';
    //$bdd = new $classDB;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nothing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
          $bdd->ShowClientList();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    //or should I load the class here?

    //include "/var/www/php/db.php";
    //$classDB = 'DB';
    //$bdd = new $classDB;
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You  have to put it *anywhere before the code that depends on it is called*. Otherwise where you place it won't affect performance.

Many applications typically include files they are dependent on at the top of the file as it makes it easier t keep track of what you're using that way.

Comment: Should I add it after the `charset` statement or that wont change anything?

Comment: That won't affect it. The PHP code is executed on the server. The browser only sees the HTML it produces.